# Suppose that O, A and B are three non-collinear points in a plane

Tags: vectors

Let OC := OB − 2OA, OD := OB + 3OA and OE := −OA

(a) Express the vector OM in terms of the vectors OA and OB, where M is the point of intersection of the line through O and C and the line through B and E.

How do i answer this

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use Mathjax and also include your trry

Answer (score 1):

Since $M$ lies on $BE$,

$$\overrightarrow{OM}=t\overrightarrow{OE}+(1-t)\overrightarrow{OB}=-t\overrightarrow{OA}+(1-t)\overrightarrow{OB}$$

for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

As  $\overrightarrow{OC}=-2\overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{OB}$ and $\overrightarrow{OC}//\overrightarrow{OM}$,

\begin{align}
\frac{-t}{-2}&=\frac{1-t}{1}\\
t&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}

Therefore, $\displaystyle OM=-\frac{2}{3}\overrightarrow{OA}+\frac{1}{3}\overrightarrow{OB}$.

Comment: @kulthum Just a little addition about the line equation : $M=B+t\vec {BE}$ so expressed with vectors this gives $\vec{OM}=\vec{OB}+t(\vec{BO}+\vec{OE})$ which is the equation given here after we have regrouped terms.